# how about (subjunctive?)

Tags: idiomatic-language, subjunctives, informal-language

There's this construct in informal speech:

```
How about + clause.
```

When used in the affirmative, things are clear enough:

```
 - "How about you shut up?"
 - "How about we give them a hand, huh?" etc.
```

But not so much when used in the negative. This is what my question is about. Should the negative be a subjunctive or not? 
That is:

```
 - How about you don't do a damn thing until I tell you to?
 - How about you not do a damn thing until I tell you to?
```

Comment: The second one is wrong. "you not do" doesn't ever make sense.

Comment: @corsaka - it's fine.

Comment: @Corsaka how about "it's crucial that you not do anything until you get word from us". It's formal, but the correct form, as far as I know. Using "don't" here would be technically incorrect, although still used informally and (in my experience) more so in British English than American English, where the subjunctive is used more often

Comment: Ah, that might be why. I'm British.